# Send HTML mail body which support Outlook from java mail

Tags: java, html, email

I am using the below code which works well in browsers, but does not display as properly formatted in Outlook:

```
MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = new MimeMultipart();
MimeBodyPart bodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

bodyPart.setText("<html><body><font size='3px' face='Times New Roman'>"
    + removeMultipleSpaces(msgbody) + "</font></body></html>");
mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(bodyPart);
bodyPart.setDescription("Text");
bodyPart.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8" );
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what the actual problem is?

Comment: It may be because of Outlooks support, try looking here to see if everything is supported; http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: But what is the problem? _What_ is not displayed correctly, and exactly _how_ is it incorrect? Also, what you posted seems to be OK, the content of the `msgBody` would be interesting to see...

Comment: I m sending byte code of image in html <img> tag. but image is not get displayed in outlook.It works fine in browser.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention in the comment, you want to add an image. Create a MimeBodyPart for the image, create a cid, and do setContentID on the MimeBodyPart of the image:

```
import javax.mail.internet.*;

MimeMultipart content = new MimeMultipart("related");

MimeBodyPart mainPart = new MimeBodyPart();
mainPart.setText("<html><body><img src=\"cid:123456789@localhost\"></body></html>","UTF-8", "html");
content.addBodyPart(mainPart);

MimeBodyPart imagePart = new MimeBodyPart();

java.net.URL img1 = Example.class.getClassLoader().getResource("image.png");
imagePart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(img1));
//or:
//imagePart.attachFile("resources/image.png");

imagePart.setContentID("<123456789@localhost>");   // to embed
imagePart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);  // to embed
content.addBodyPart(imagePart);
```